# What is the meaning of صبر (tying up) of animals?

Tags: fiqh, hadith-interpretation

What did Prophet (S) mean when he said,

> نهى رسول الله ـ صلى الله عليه وسلم ـ عن صبر البهائم
>
> “The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) forbade tying up animals.”
>
> [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1956a), [Sunan Ibn Majah 3186](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:3186)

does it mean it is haram to tie a cow, we do it all the time in farms or other places where we keep it.

Comment: The version of ibn Majah doesn't quote the full information about the situation where the prophet() expressed this prohibition.

Answer (score 4):

The prohibition is on tying up an animal and then using it as a target for archery etc. It is not about tying up cattle to manage them which is a common practice and is acceptable as long as you feed them.

The hadith of Sahih Muslim makes it more clear:

> سمعت هشام بن زيد بن أنس بن مالك ، قال : دخلت مع جدي أنس بن مالك دار الحكم بن أيوب ، فإذا قوم قد نصبوا دجاجة يرمونها ، قال: فقال أنس: نهى رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم أن تصبر البهائم
>
> Hisham bin Zaid bin Anas bin Malik said: "I entered, the house of Al-Hakam bin Ayyub along with my grandfather Anas bin Malik, and there were some people who had made a hen a target and were shooting arrows at her. Anas said: 'The Messenger of Allah (s.a.w) forbade taking animals as targets."'
>
> <sup>— [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1956a)</sup>

> قال العلماء صبر البهائم أن تحبس وهي حية لتقتل بالرمي ونحوه
>
> The scholars said that  صبر of animals is imprisoning them while they are alive so that they can be killed by archery and the like
>
> <sup>— [Sharah Nawawi](https://shamela.ws/book/1711/2918#p1)</sup>